# Выдаёт ошибку при импорте диспетчера на питоне библиотеки поставил, всё должно работать

Tags: python

Питон выдает ошибку

```
C:\PythonProjcts\python_beginners_course-main\pythonProject3\Scripts\python.exe C:\Windows\bot\main.py  
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Windows\bot\main.py", line 3, in <module> 
    from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher 
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatcher' from 'aiogram.dispatcher' (C:\PythonProjcts\python_beginners_course-main\pythonProject3\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\__init__.py). Did you mean: 'dispatcher'? 
 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Что делать?

Comment: Делать то, что ты ещё не сделал - прочитать ошибку.

Comment: Имена файлов и пути проверил всё в порядке

Answer (score 0):

Вместо вашего

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
```

примените

```
from aiogram import Dispatcher
```

(т. е. **без** `.dispatcher`), или

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher import Dispatcher
```

(т.е. **дважды** `.dispatcher`)

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что то же самое сообщение об ошибке??? А не какое-то другое? Потому что во втором случае мой ответ вам помог.:-)

Comment: Ну да ругается всё так же на диспетчер в 3 строке, могу показать сам код, а то уже 5 часов пофиксить не могу

Comment: Но не может ругаться на то же самое, когда вы **изменили** 3-ю строку для моего ответа. Прочитайте тщательно текст ошибки.

Comment: Теперь в вашей программе 3-я строка `from aiogram import Dispatcher`, но в тексте ошибки ругается на 3-ю строку `from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher`. **Значит, вы исправляете одну программу, но запускаете другую, неисправленную.** (Например в PyCharm вы используете Shift+F10 вместо Ctrl+Shift+F10).

Answer (score 0):

@MarianD  Да, ругается теперь выглядит вот так часть кода с импортом

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hlink, hbold, hitalic
from aiogram.utils.emoji import emojize
from aiogram.utils.deep_linking import decode_payload
from aiogram.types import ParseMode, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton
from aiogram.types.inline_keyboard import InlineKeyboardButton, 
InlineKeyboardMarkup
from requests import get
import sqlite3
```

а ошибка выглядит так

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Windows\bot\main.py", line 3, in <module>
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
ImportError: cannot import name 'Dispatcher' from 'aiogram.dispatcher' 
 (C:\PythonProjcts\python_beginners_course-main\pythonProject6\Lib\site- 
packages\aiogram\dispatcher\__init__.py). Did you mean: 'dispatcher'?
```

Comment: Я автор вопроса, просто залогинился и не могу обратно на акк вернутся(

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: from 'aiogram.dispatcher' ? Слушай у тебя не соответствие того кода что ты показываешь с тем который реально запускается.

Comment: Да, я показал там отрезок кода в котором ошибку выдаёт в остальном вроде всё ровно